# Blur function for cs50 pset4

Tags: c, cs50

What am i doing wrong? I tried diff tricks too. Used 3 for loops doesnt seem to work as well for me... Can anyone help to make sure what is wrong or what is right. The code seems to compile well but the output is not correct

code:

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
   double sr;
    double sg;
    double sb;
    int total=1;

    double sur1=0;
    double sug1=0;
    double sub1=0;

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            sr=image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            sg=image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            sb=image[i][j].rgbtBlue;

            int k = -1;
            int l = -1;

                while(k < 2)
                {
                    int y = j - k;

                    if(y >= 0)
                    {
                        double sr1 = image[i][y].rgbtRed;
                        sur1 = sur1 + sr1;

                        double sg1 = image[i][y].rgbtGreen;
                        sug1 = sug1 + sg1;

                        double sb1 = image[i][y].rgbtBlue;
                        sub1 = sub1 + sb1;

                        total++;
                    }

                        k++;
                }

                while(l < 2)
                {
                    int x = i - l;

                    if(x >= 0)
                    {
                        double sr2 = image[x][j].rgbtRed;
                        sur1 = sur1 + sr2 ;

                        double sg2 = image[x][j].rgbtGreen;
                        sug1 = sug1 + sg2;

                        double sb2 = image[x][j].rgbtBlue;
                        sub1 = sub1 + sb2;

                        total++;
                    }
                    l++;
                }

                    sur1=sur1+sr;
                    sug1=sug1+sg;
                    sub1=sub1+sb;


                    int avgr=round(sur1/total);
                    int avgg=round(sug1/total);
                    int avgb=round(sub1/total);


                    image[i][j].rgbtRed=avgr;
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen=avgg;
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue=avgb;

                    total=1;
            }

        }

        return;
}
```

If anyone want information about this:
https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/filter/less/

Made some changes
still no desired answer
Code:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int total=0;

    for (int i=0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {

            double sur1=0;
            double sug1=0;
            double sub1=0;
            int k = -1;
            int l = -1;

                while(l < 2)
                {
                    int x = i - l;

                    if(x >= 0)
                    {

                        while(k < 2)
                        {
                            int y = j - k;
                            if(y >= 0)
                            {
                                double sr1 = image[x][y].rgbtRed;
                                sur1 = sur1 + sr1;

                                double sg1 = image[x][y].rgbtGreen;
                                sug1 = sug1 + sg1;

                                double sb1 = image[x][y].rgbtBlue;
                                sub1 = sub1 + sb1;

                                total++;
                                k++;

                            }

                            else
                            {
                                k++;
                            }
                         }

                         l++;
                    }

                        else
                        {
                            l++;
                        }
                    }

                    image[i][j].rgbtRed=round(sur1/total);
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen=round(sug1/total);
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue=round(sub1/total);
                    total=0;

               }
        }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I do not think you understood well how to implement blur filter into the code. Start thinking about corners, edges.. The pixels in the middle are easy to filter, but edges and corners need to be taken care in seperate "if conditions".

Comment: could u help me a little? I cant even get the middle one right

Comment: To apply blur to one pixel, you need to calculate (average) the RGB values of the pixels around that pixel. Start thinking about here. Then how this calculation would be different on left upper corner, upper edge, upper right corner etc.. Go step by step.

Comment: i guess i did for edges. i kept condition if y > 0
if y < 0 it doesnt execute which is the edges